# Showing a different view for treeview item selected

Tags: wpf

I am trying to build a help module with a treeview and the goal is to have a different view show up in the redbox based on selected treeview item. how would I go about to do that?

[image]

This is all the code I have:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <TreeView Margin="2" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" IsEnabled="True" FontSize="20">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Introduction">

            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Logging in" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Changing Password" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Home" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Dashboard Elements" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Parking Spots" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
                <TreeViewItem Header="Docking Spots"  Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Log Table" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Security" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Domestic Trucks" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="International Trucks" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Administration" Margin="0,10,0,0" Visibility="{Binding Source={x:Static model:ViewModel.CurrentUser}, Path=IsAdmin, Converter={StaticResource My.Converter.BoolToHidden}}">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Permissions" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Editing a User" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Adding a new company" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
            </TreeViewItem>

        </TreeView>



    </Grid>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have only tried to do it like tab pages which didn't help at all. I don't know how to go about doing it and I have tried searching for it too but it's just treeviews in the examples no showing of different views.

Comment: Please, share your code with attempts, it can help other to figure out your issue

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I have added the code that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really think that this `Control` is not doing what you expect. I would rather use Markdown to create a help file and save it to `html`, `pdf` or `xps`. You can open this document when the user hits the help button. IMO it is not a good idea to "hard-code" a Help module.

But to answer your question any way, you can do it this way:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TreeView x:Name="TreeView_TOC">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Chapeter 1">
            <TreeViewItem.Tag>
                <TextBlock Text="Your Content goes here" />
            </TreeViewItem.Tag>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>

    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" 
                    Content="{Binding ElementName=TreeView_TOC, Path=SelectedItem.Tag, Mode=OneWay}"/>

</Grid>
```

Happy documenting

Tim